# replicate current path with color in C

Tags: c, shell

I'm using Linux Ubuntu and I would like to replicate the current path of the terminate with coloring. In essence, I want to my program to print `\u@\h:\w$` like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/601181/how-to-display-current-path-in-command-prompt-in-linuxs-sh-not-bash) post with the coloring of the user's terminal. In other words, exactly replicate the path of `(user)@(host):(pwd)$` down to the coloring.

---

Two problem I'm running in to:

1) I'm trying to use `system("\u@\h:\w$ ")`, but I can't escape the special characters no matter what I do.

2) I can't find what colors the users are using.

Comment: See here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46562/how-do-you-colorize-only-some-keywords-for-a-bash-script

Comment: If you set your prompt to that with `PS1='\u@\h:\w$'`, you'll see that it's not colored. Colors require adding ansi escapes.

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues here.
Parsing `PS1` enviromental variable is done by the shell. Shell (e.g. bash) is converting '\u' string into '(user)'. This is not a system call.
[System](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) call executes a filename, so by doing `system("\u@\h:\w$ ")` you want to execute a program called `\u@\h:\w$`. I don't think you have a program called like that on your system and this is not your intention. You want to print currently logged username, not execute a program called '\u'. You want to execute program called [whoami](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/whoami.1.html) which will print the user name of the current user.
I don't know what colors do you want. Coloring in unix shells is done using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). You just printf bunch of characters and your terminal will color all following characters.
Printing this exact output with a C program is more complicated than that, anyway challenge awaits. The following program will print the output of `(user)@(host):(pwd)$`. The part `(user)@` will be red, the part `(host):` will be yellow and the part `(pwd)$` will be in magenta. I am using [popen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) posix call to execute a process and get it's output.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ANSI_COLOR_RED     "\x1b[31m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_GREEN   "\x1b[32m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW  "\x1b[33m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BLUE    "\x1b[34m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA "\x1b[35m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_CYAN    "\x1b[36m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_RESET   "\x1b[0m"

void exec_and_grab_output(const char cmd[], char *outbuf, size_t outbuflen) {
    size_t outbufpos = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    char tmpbuf[100];
    /* Open the command for reading. */  
    fp = popen(cmd, "r");
    assert(fp != NULL);
    /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
    while (fgets(tmpbuf, sizeof(tmpbuf)-1, fp) != NULL) {
        assert(outbufpos <= outbuflen);
        const size_t tmpbufpos = strlen(tmpbuf);
        memcpy(&outbuf[outbufpos], tmpbuf, tmpbufpos);
        outbufpos += tmpbufpos;
    }
    /* close */
    pclose(fp);
}

int main()
{
    char outbuf[2048];

    exec_and_grab_output("whoami", outbuf, sizeof(outbuf));
    printf(ANSI_COLOR_RED);
    assert(strlen(outbuf) > 2);
    outbuf[strlen(outbuf)-2] = '\0'; // remove newline from output
    printf("%s@", outbuf); // this will be red

    exec_and_grab_output("hostname", outbuf, sizeof(outbuf));
    printf(ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW);
    assert(strlen(outbuf) > 2);
    outbuf[strlen(outbuf)-2] = '\0'; // remove newline from output
    printf("%s:", outbuf); // this will be yellow

    exec_and_grab_output("pwd", outbuf, sizeof(outbuf));
    printf(ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA);
    assert(strlen(outbuf) > 2);
    outbuf[strlen(outbuf)-2] = '\0'; // remove newline from output
    printf("%s$", outbuf); // this will be in magenta

    printf(ANSI_COLOR_RESET);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to color the output of the PS1 variable in shell (not in C, C is a programming language, shell is a program), you may type that in your bash terminal:

```
export PS1="\033[31m\u@\033[33m\h:\033[36m\w$\033[0m"
```

The `\033[31m` part corresponds 1:1 with the `"\x1b[31m"` part in the C program above. Bash will print `\033[31m` characters to the terminal (when prinring PS1) and the terminal will then color all following chracters to red. Bash will expand `\u` to the name of the current user. And so on.